# Delay in starting command prompt

Tags: windows, command-line, bash, terminal, powershell

There is a weird problem with my command prompt.
Whenever I start it, there's a delay. The windows opens quickly as it should, but there is a Blank Time, before the command line displays this message:

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.3.9600]
(c) 2013 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
```

This delay doesn't seem random, its always like 3 seconds. The blank period appears something like this (the cursor is blinking) -

[image]

The exact same problem also occurs with-

> - Batch file
> - Powershell
> - Git Bash
> - Cygwin Bash Terminal

This thing only started happening recently.

If you think my system is slow, then I have no background running programs. And earlier it used to be perfect.

And by the way- How much system resources would a simple command window require?

What could have happened, and How do I fix it?

Comment: Maybe from admin elevated cmd run `sfc /scannow`, run a disk cleanup to the entire system which you can use one of the PS examples I wrote about here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28852786/automate-process-of-disk-cleanup-cleanmgr-exe-without-user-intervention/64106041#64106041 and then afterwards reboot and see if the problem persists. Otherwise, check your AV or antimalware software and make an exception for cmd.exe, powershell.exe and other executables that start slow and see if that helps. Quick ideas basically.

Comment: just a thought but if you do `cmd /?` then it will show you two autorun registry locations maybe make sure they are both blank?  otherwise perhaps could be a delay there?

Comment: @PimpJuiceIT Thanks for the suggestion. Believe me or not, IT WORKED. Not exactly sfc, but when I ran the command, it asked me to restart to finish installing some updates. And all that it required was the restart. Everything's good now. (I had no hope tbh ).  BTW, what should a do of this question? Should I delete it?

Comment: You could delete it or add a self-answer for the full solution with the detail from your comment in case someone else has this issue, your advice and findings might help someone else resolve this too.