# Delay in Command Prompt startup After Windows 11 Update

Tags: windows, command-line, cmd.exe, windows-11, windows-11-v23h2

I'm encountering an issue with Windows 11 where there's a noticeable delay (about 2 seconds) in the text appearance when I launch the terminal. The terminal window itself pops up right away, but the command prompt text takes its time. This started after a recent update.

Here's a comprehensive list of troubleshooting steps I've already taken:

1. Ran the System File Checker (sfc).
2. Executed DISM (Deployment Image Servicing and Management) commands.
3. Used the Microsoft Software Removal Tool.
4. Reinstalled Windows while keeping personal data intact.

Unfortunately, these attempts haven't resolved the issue. I also found a [similar thread](https://superuser.com/questions/1597940/delay-in-starting-command-prompt) here, but the solutions provided there didn't work for me either.

This delay is more than just an annoyance as it's affecting my productivity significantly due to the nature of my work as a developer.

Has anyone else faced this issue and found a workaround or solution? Any help or insights would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

No issue here on any of my Windows 11 Pro machines.  CMD starts right away. Windows 11 Pro 23H2  22631.3007

You ran SFC and DISM.  Make sure in the correct order (SFC follows DISM).  Run the complete sequence again.

> (1) Open cmd.exe with Run as Administrator.
>
> (2) DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-image /StartComponentCleanup
>
> (3) DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-Image /Restorehealth
>
> (4) SFC /SCANNOW
>
> (5) Restart when all the above is complete and test.

Then if the above still fails to correct things, run a Windows 11 Repair Install with Keep Everything.

Go to the Windows Media Creation Link

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows11

> Windows 11 is running, so click on the Download button (not Upgrade
> Button) and select Download.  Run the downloaded file  (double click
> on it).  You will need a USB key as running the download creates a USB
> Key. Run Setup on the USB Key. This will launch the Repair.   Proceed
> normally answering the prompts.

The default Keep prompt is to Keep Everything.

Let us hope this fixes your issue, for the remaining step is to back everything up and reinstall Windows 11.